# How to run bash script in a for loop?

Tags: bash

I have multiple .vcf.gz files that look like this: (and there is 22 of them)

```
ALL.chr1.phase3_shapeit2_mvncall_integrated_v5a.20130502.genotypes.vcf.gz
ALL.chr2.phase3_shapeit2_mvncall_integrated_v5a.20130502.genotypes.vcf.gz
ALL.chr3.phase3_shapeit2_mvncall_integrated_v5a.20130502.genotypes.vcf.gz
...
ALL.chr22.phase3_shapeit2_mvncall_integrated_v5a.20130502.genotypes.vcf.gz
```

And I have a script filter.sh which can run on one file that looks like this. How would I loop trough all those 22 files?

```
filter_and_convert ()
{
echo -ne "varID\t" 
bcftools view $1 -S $2 --force-samples -Ou |  bcftools query -l | tr '\n' '\t' | sed 's/\t$/\n/'       

#The first python inline script will check if a variant is blacklisted
NOW=$(date +%Y-%m-%d/%H:%M:%S)
echo "Starting at $NOW"
bcftools view -S $2 --force-samples $1 -Ou | \
bcftools query -f '%ID[\t%GT]\n' | \
awk '
{
for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    if (substr($i,0,1) == "c") {
        printf("%s",$i)
    } else if ( substr($i, 0, 1) == ".") {
        printf("\tNA")
    } else if ($i ~ "[0-9]|[0-9]") {
        n = split($i, array, "|")
        printf("\t%d",array[1]+array[2])
        } else {
        #printf("\t%s",$i)
        printf("Unexpected: %s",$i)
       exit 1
    }
}
printf("\n")
}
'

NOW=$(date +%Y-%m-%d/%H:%M:%S)
echo "Ending at $NOW"
}

filter_and_convert ALL.chr22.phase3_shapeit2_mvncall_integrated_v5a.20130502.genotypes.vcf.gz  samples.txt
```

Comment: `for file in *.vcf.gz; do filter_and_convert "$file"; done`

Comment: do you mean put this line in my filter.sh script of run this on my filter.sh script like: for file in *.vcf.gz; do filter_and_convert "$file"; done   where I would replace name of the file in my filter.sh script with $file?

Comment: You replace the last line of the script with that.

Comment: Oh, it also needs `samples.txt` after `"$file"`. I didn't see that before.

Comment: What is `$3` supposed to be in the function? You only give two arguments.

Comment: Hi Sorry that was from the previous version of script. I removed it and edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
filter_and_convert ALL.chr22.phase3_shapeit2_mvncall_integrated_v5a.20130502.genotypes.vcf.gz  samples.txt
```

with a `for` loop that calls the function on all the files that match a wildcard.

```
for file in ALL.*.vcf.gz; do
    filter_and_convert "$file"  samples.txt
done
```

Comment: I did put your code at the end of my script and run it like this: sh filter.sh > output.txt Does this make sense if I want to have output of each 22 files processed in teh loop concatenated in the output.txt? Also this seems to run forever....it's been probably 10 hours since I started running it and it yet didn't finish. Is there is a more efficiant way to run this?

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script so you can see what it's doing.

Comment: I did it hangs after this line:
}
printf("\n")
}
'

Comment: is there is any input on this or do you need more info?

Comment: I tried running this for one file and it completed. My question is to run this using the loop you provided do I run it like this: sh filter.sh > output.txt or sh filter.sh >> output.txt In other words how do I ensure that output of all 22 loop iterations is in this one file: output.txt?

Comment: would to output everything in one file I put this in your loop: for file in ALL.*.vcf.gz; do
   filter_and_convert "$file"  samples.txt >> output.txt
done

Answer (score 0):

```
v="ALL.chr"
p=".phase3_shapeit2_mvncall_integrated_v5a.20130502.genotypes.vcf.gz"
for i in {1..22};
do
        file=$v$i$p
        bash filter.sh $file sample.txt
done
```

Use this file variable with your script. It should work. I am assuming first argument to your filer.sh is filename. Rest of the argument you can add

Comment: Thanks for gettign back to me. Can you please edit your answer with how exactly my filter.sh script would look like?